# what statistics should I use for demonstrating two data points

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I want to plot a time-series of emissions of a pollutant. **For each year, I only have two data,** one min value and one max value for the emissions.

I only demonstrated the min, max and mean value in the time-series figure, but my boss said it was not enough. Should I use mean plus standard errors or Confidence Intervals or SD or others? and why it is better than just demonstrate min-mean-max?

Comment: You said you have only min and max, then you say about using mean, standard error etc-- do you have them?

Comment: I calculated the mean and standard error with the min and max

Comment: How exactly? You need to tell us more about your data: I understand that you made some distributional assumptions in here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have JUST the min and max, there is literally nothing you can do per year except plot those values. Even the mean calculated from min and max will be meaingless and misleading if any data driven bussiness decisions are to be made. What you could (and I'm not saying should) do is regressional analysis (trendline). This would show and give a rough prediction whether those values are going to increase or decrease in the future.

If you could obtain more data than just min and max, please consider doing that. You can remind your boss that incomplete data leads to bad decisions and financial loss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with minimum and maximum, is that they may not represent well the distribution of the variable.

Consider for example a sample of size 25 of variable x that looks like this (when we present the observations from small to big):

20,25,28,29,29,32,32,35,37,37,38,40,41,41,44,45,46,46,46,48,51,53,71,74,212

Then the mean is 48, the minimum is 20, and the maximum is 212.
If someone would tell you these 3 numbers, you would never guess that 212 is just a single observation that is irregular, you would think that the distribution is something like this:
[image: Illustration]

While in fact the distribution is not like that, there's just one very non-representing observation (212) that caused the maximum to be as it is. 
We call such observations/values that are very different from the others, and don't represent the data, "[outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier)".
When you have many observation (e.g. hundreds), then there is usually a high probability that the maximum and/or minimum will be outliers that don't represent the data.

**One approach** to this problem is to draw the mean with a [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for the mean, which can be calculated by taking the mean and adding/subtracting (for the lower and upper bound of the interval, respectively) the standard deviation multiplied by 1.96 (for 95% confidence level). E.g. if the mean is 10 and standard deviation is 2, then the confidence interval is [10-2*1.96 , 10+2*1.96].

**Another approach**, which is even more robust (is not affected easily by outliers) is to draw the median, and the [interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range). You can draw the mean as well.

In [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)), the [boxplot](https://www.r-bloggers.com/box-plot-with-r-tutorial/) function creates a [box plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) such that the box represents the interquartile range, a line inside the box represents the median, and observations outside the interquartile range are drawn as points.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and suggestions!!

Comment: I find the confidential intervals are too large, the results are way bigger and smaller than the max and min values, respectively. Do you have any advice on this case? the two data point I have are the max and min values.

Comment: It might happen if the distribution is such that observations are focused near the minimum and maximum, and not in the middle. Can you draw a graph of the data?

Of course, the option of drawing the median and interquartile range (and you can add more percentiles as you like, e.g. 10% and 90% percentiles) is always available, and will never yield results outside the min-max range.

Comment: yes, because the only two data points I have for each year are the min and max. I have adjusted the percentiles to 10% and 90%, the CI results still exceed the min and max...only percentiles that won't generate bigger-than-max or smaller-than-min CI values are 0.25/0.75. As the t-value is 1...which represents the mean+stand error; the results are equal to the min and max. Actually I don't see the point to do statistics analysis for only two data points. Do you think it is necessary?

Comment: I didn't understand you have only two data points, minimum and maximum.

If that is really all you have, then I see no point in showing anything besides the min and the max (I wouldn't even show the mean, as the mean between the min and max is not the same as the real mean over the year).

I would simply draw two lines, ones for the minimum values (say in red) and ones for the maximum values over the years (say in blue).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the maximums for several observations, those maximums actually follow a [GEV distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem).

Comment: Could you be more elaborate why maximums follow the GPD or provide a source maybe?

Comment: Ah, source provided with a correction.